# How does format.html know what to render?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following piece of code in the file app/mailers/user_mailer.rb . 
Now how does format.html know what to render . 
It is not in the action of any controller.
I understand the basic fact that it renders show view by default but here is no controller no action. 
How does it still work ?

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def SIGNUP_NOTIFICATION(user)
    @recipients = "#{user.email}"
    @from = "#{sender.email}"
    mailer_name = "SIGNUP_NOTIFICATION"
    mail(:to => @recipients, :from => @from) do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right that ActionMailer is not a controller (that's ActionController). The `respond_to` method of ActionController and the `mail` method of ActionMailer are entirely different things, however they both have the concept of "what kind of response should we be sending" and so the rails devs chose to offer a similar interface for format picking in both.

In ActionController the `respond_to` method takes a block and uses the HTTP request environment to pick which format to render.

In ActionMailer, `mail` takes a block and uses different logic to decide which format to render. When you give it `format.html` it simply looks in your views folder for templates with `<method_name>.<format>.<acceptable_template_type>`, e.g., SIGNUP_NOTIFICATION.html.erb. As an aside, you should name all your methods in snake_case (signup_notification). Uppercase method names are non-idiomatic and might cause problems.

**Technical explanation**

While you don't need to know this to use ActionMailer, I think it's interesting to walk through the flow of how template generation works here. It includes some interesting meta-programming but the logic is simpler than in regular controllers (no HTTP environment).

You can see in the [source for mail](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9b72c36783516f5ef8f2fac5f6f342a6a48d8d78/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb#L648) that it calls [a function to render the messages](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9b72c36783516f5ef8f2fac5f6f342a6a48d8d78/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb#L692). If you gave `mail` a block, mail creates an instance of [ActionMailer::Collector](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9b72c36783516f5ef8f2fac5f6f342a6a48d8d78/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/collector.rb) (which includes AbstractController::Collector) and yields to this collector. So, in your example the collector gets the function `html` called on it (since your `do |format| ... end` has an argument, `format` will be the collector instance when `yield(collector)` is called [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9b72c36783516f5ef8f2fac5f6f342a6a48d8d78/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb#L697).

So an instance of ActionMailer::Collector is passed into your `do |format| ...` block, where it has the function `html` called on it, The collector uses [method missing tricks](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fcdb5dc55729f4939e9a5064dfee8eef2dec4316/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/collector.rb#L21)
 from AbstractController::Collector so that it can respond to any mime type, passing the requested type over to `ActionMailler::Collector#custom` which actually builds the email by looking in the views folder for templates matching that type.

Answer (score 0):

Mailer is like a controller but without inheriting ActionController, for your mailer you would put your view in `app/views/user_mailer/SIGNUP_NOTIFICATION.html.erb`

And you can send this email calling the method in your mailer:

```
UserMailer.SIGNUP_NOTIFICATION(some_user_instance).deliver
```

I am not sure if this is what you are asking for.